# How to get ALL facebook friends score - Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I want a facebook leaderboard to show friends' scores. My issue is that friends who have given "only me" publish_action permission will not be shown in the leaderboard.

Is there a trick to get friends score from the facebook api even with "only me" visibility ?

I could store facebookid & scores for each player in another database (so I guess I would not need to use the facebook score api anymore), get the friend list from facebook and get the friends' scores from my database, but it's a bit more complicated and Im not sure Facebook would find it ok.

Thank you,

Alex

Comment: _“Is there a trick to get friends score from the facebook api even with "only me" visibility ?”_ – if there was, it would only mean that this setting wasn’t doing what it is supposed to, and that Facebook would need to fix it.

Comment: I agree, but what if I store the players' scores & facebookids in my own database then create the leaderboard with these info & the facebook friends list ?

Comment: Sure, you can do that.